# no conflict between int max,a variable and int max(int ,int),a function in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces

This is a valid code even though there is a conflict between the **max**, a global variable and **max(int , int )**, a function inside **namespace std**.

Why there is no error?

```
using namespace std;
int max;
int main()
{
  int c;
  c=max;
  //c=max(5,3);
}
```

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Comment: And your question is? Are you wonder why you don't get an error from the compiler? Something else?

Comment: edited...
Why there is no error?

Comment: have you tried adding `#include <algorithm>`? it needs to be there for a meaningful question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't included `<algorithm>`, or any other header that might declare `std::max`, so there is no conflict. Your program only declares one entity called `max`.

If I include that header, I get the expected error due to the ambiguity:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:8:5: error: reference to ‘max’ is ambiguous
   c=max;
```

the solution to which is not to dump `std` into the global namespace, nullifying the whole purpose of the namespace.

Comment: You might add that any standard C++ header may include any other.  So if you `#include <iostream>`, you might indirectly get `<algorithm>`.  Or not, which means that the code might compile on one system, and not on another.